# I'm working on a Next.js project and encountering an issue with API routes where the req.query object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Problem:
I'm trying to access query parameters in my API route, but for some reason, `req.query` doesn't seem to contain any data. Always getting "invalid"datat

## Thats the API Request

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../db/db_connection';

export async function GET(req) {
    const { datum } = req.query;
    const connection = await connectToDatabase();

    const query = `SELECT terminuhrzeit FROM termine WHERE termindatum = ?`;
    const [gebuchteTermine] = await connection.execute(query, [datum]);
    await connection.end();

    const gebuchteZeiten = gebuchteTermine.map(termin => termin.terminuhrzeit);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(gebuchteZeiten), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}
```

## Frontend Code:

```
const handleDayClick = async (day) => {
    // ...
    const formattedMonth = currentMonth + 1 < 10 ? `0${currentMonth + 1}` : currentMonth + 1;
    const formattedDay = day < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;
    const selectedDate = `${currentYear}-${formattedMonth}-${formattedDay}`;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/verfuegbareZeiten?datum=${selectedDate}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setGebuchteZeiten(data); // Update state with fetched booked times
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching booked times', error);
    }
};
```

I have verified that the frontend is sending the correct URL: http://localhost:3000/api/verfuegbareZeiten?datum=2024-01-30. However, when I try to log req.query in my API route, it outputs undefined.

Things I've tried:

Checking the URL and ensuring that the query parameters are being sent correctly.
Restarting the Next.js server.
Testing the API endpoint with Postman, which results in the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The request object in NextJS API handlers has no 'query' property.

If you want to access the query params, you can use `request.nextUrl.searchParams` property which is a `URLSearchParams` object. Here is an [official example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#url-query-parameters):

```
export function GET(request) {
  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams
  const query = searchParams.get('query')
  // query is "hello" for /api/search?query=hello
}
```

[In this documentation page](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request#nexturl), you can learn more about all of the properties that NextJS has added to [the built-in `Request` object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)